# Does a question mark at the beginning of a symbol name have any special meaning in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

In this example (from [here](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/sente)):

```
(defmethod event-msg-handler :chsk/recv
  [{:as ev-msg :keys [?data]}]
  (logf "Push event from server: %s" ?data)))
```

where `?data` is `vector`, does the `?` have any purpose or signify something?

Comment: It looks like it's just a naming convention. I think he uses it for optional parameters, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951761/what-are-the-allowed-characters-in-a-clojure-keyword

Answer (score 5):

The question mark does not change the way that Clojure reads or evaluates the symbol. A symbol that contains a question mark is treated in exactly the same way by Clojure as a symbol that does not.

The use of the ? in the ?data symbol is therefore just a naming convention used by the author of the Sente library.

Comment: Yes, in this specific case I believe the author of the Sente library uses a leading `?` to indicate an optional/nillable function parameter.  While the parameter must be passed, it can safely be nil.  It seems somewhat of a riff from the Swift programming language's optional type syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Generally punctuation in symbols is a naming convention. a trailing `?` usually indicates a predicate function or some boolean flag.

Examples in the core api are things like `map?` and `number?`. An example might look like this:

```
=> (filter number? [1 "foo" 2 :bar]) 
(1 2)
=> (remove number? [1 "foo" 2 :bar])
("foo" :bar)
=> (def debug? true)
(when debug? (println "Debugging")
```

a trailing `!` generally indicates that some in place mutation is occuring, e.g

```
=>(def an-atom (atom 0))
=> @an-atom 
0
=> (reset! an-atom  10)
=> @an-atom
10
```

However, some libraries do attach further meaning. For example cascalog uses leading `?` `!!` and `!` to indicate some differing properties of query output vars. See [The Cascalog Docs](http://cascalog.org/) for more information

Comment: What about leading `?`